# Are there any differences? - to buy x to purchase

Tags: meaning, verbs, differences

Are there any differences between the meanings of "purchase" and "buy"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked them up in a dictionary? What did that tell you? What is still unclear to you? Please edit your question to include these details; otherwise, the question is off-topic for this website and will likely be closed.

Comment: I didn't look for the meanings of them in a dictionary, just want to benefit from the experiences of others.

Comment: That’s not how Stack Exchange sites work. They are meant to be a place where you can ask questions if you cannot find the answer yourself. They’re not a place where people just answer any little thing you think of for you; you’re expected to do your own homework, and then the community helps you when your own efforts are no longer enough.

Comment: I get it. sorry for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"to buy" is the normal word, "to purchase"  is an elevated variant. I don't think that it is often used in normal everyday language. You don't purchase a Coke or a hamburger. "To purchase" is from Norman-French.

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't very much difference, and they are almost universally interchangeable.